# Как задать путь к файлу не указывая директорию E: где он и находится

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, .net-4.8

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
            string source = @"E:\диплом\Auto\шаблон.docx";
            doc = app.Documents.Add(source);
```

здесь я создаю документ ворд новый по типу своего шаблона
путь к шаблону указал в строке source. Код то рабочий но подскажите как указать путь к файлу не указывая саму директорию по типу относительной адресации к файлу
я пробовал так писать: @"..\диплом\Auto\шаблон.docx"; но ничего не вышло так он не ищет файл

Comment: Тип приложения, версия дотнета?

Comment: приложение составленное на C# WinForms ну а платформа тут роль не играет

Comment: Версия дотнета имеет значение.

Comment: версия 4.8.04084

Comment: видимо .net framework

Comment: да эта версия net framework а вам не это надо?

Comment: `string source = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\диплом\Auto\шаблон.docx");`

Comment: не работает ваш вариант кода

Comment: Я не могу угадать, где у вас что на диске. `MessageBox.Show(source);` попробуйте разобраться, где что лежит. Вы просили способ указать путь относительно исполняемого файла, я указал.

Comment: сам файл на флеш-накопителе находится поэтому и думаю как указать путь без директории так как в разных пк буква директории меняется и файл уже прога не найдет

Comment: Не проще ли дать пользователю самому его найти? Например показать диалог открытия файла? Могу показать, как.

Comment: так я создаю файл ворд новый из другого файла в шаблоне содержится сам шаблон документа где содержится некоторая информация и так прога бы делал копии исходя из родительского файла

Comment: но я понял о чем вы говорите

Comment: Тогда почему бы не положить шаблон прямо в папку с exe файлом приложения? Тогда получится просто `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "шаблон.docx");`

Comment: до этого я не додумывался щас попробую

Comment: все вышло спасибо за помощь